# controlling a spawned picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a little game coded in c#, the game involves moving enemies.
These enemies are spawned in using the following code, this code is used multiple times to spawn multiple enemies.

```
    private void EventHandler(Action<object, EventArgs> spawnBox)
    {
        Random randomPlek = new Random();

            int xPlek;
            xPlek = randomPlek.Next(1000, 1100);

            int yPlek;
            yPlek = (randomPlek.Next(0, 8)) * 100;

            var picture = new PictureBox
            {

                Name = "pictureBoxLM",
                Size = new Size(150, 100),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                Location = new Point(xPlek, yPlek),
                Image = Leeuwenmier,

            };
            this.Controls.Add(picture);
  }
```

The problem is that when trying to make them move or collide, Visual Studio can't find the name and gives an error. This is the code i used for collision:

```
if(PbMier.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBoxLM.Bounds))
            {
            // some actions
            }
```

How can I call the spawned picturebox in the code without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms controls have names, but that doesn't mean you can access them using that name as a C# identifier.

Your PictureBox only has a named reference within `EventHandler()`, namely `picture`, but once control leaves that method that reference goes out of scope.

You need to *find* the controls again, or find another way to reference the generated controls.

So either:

```
var allPictureBoxes = this.Controls.Find("PictureBoxLM");
foreach (var pictureBox in allPictureBoxes)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or put this on your form:

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();
```

And then in the `EventHandler()`;

```
this.Controls.Add(picture);
pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
```

After which you can use this for your collision detection:

```
foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxList)
{
    // ...
}
```